# MS Access form doesn't reflect recent data updates in Split Database's FrontEnd Forms

Tags: database, microsoft-access, forms, database-administration

I have a front end and a backend to my access database. The VBA code, forms, queries etc are on the frontend and tables on the backend. The backend is on a server, about 5 different users are using copies of the frontend on their local.

When they change or enter some data, it shows/reflects quite instantly in the table in the backend, however that data is not available immediately in the forms. I am not sure why that is happening. I can see the updated data eventually in the forms but not immediately like I can see in the tables. (Ex-lets say a combobox that fetches data from a table in the backend).

Is there a table or query I can use/modify to see how often my database gets refreshed (both for tables and forms)?
Also I want to improve the performance of my split database, it works really slowly right now. Any leads would help.

Answer (score 0):

To split the frontend from the backend is a good decsion. That the DB is slow can have many reason. But mostly it's the network or a bad design.

When you reopen the form, does the form show the new data?
I remind that especially Comboboxes an Listboxes cache the Data.

*The Requery method updates the data underlying a specified control that's on the active form by requerying the source of data for the control.*

See this article https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/access.combobox.requery

Comment: no, when I reopen the form it still doesn't show me the updated data. I have tried refresh and re-query, even that doesn't work.

Comment: sounds very strange too me, have u tried to run the Front & Back and from the same location? (from the Fileserver)

Comment: I tried running Front and Back from the same location and it works. But when the backend is on the server, I can see the tables getting populated with updates, but the forms cant fetch it for some reason. Is there a way to clear cache of comboboxes via a macro or code on load of form?